# Why set a password using Jasypt when encrypting text?

Tags: java, encryption, jasypt

To encrypt a password I use (modified from http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-texts.html):

```
BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
textEncryptor.setPassword(myEncryptionPassword);
String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt(myText);
String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
```

Why is a password required to be set on `BasicTextEncryptor`?

I may be not understanding something fundamental here but does this not make sense, although it does not work :

```
BasicTextEncryptor textEncryptor = new BasicTextEncryptor();
String myEncryptedText = textEncryptor.encrypt(myText);
String plainText = textEncryptor.decrypt(myEncryptedText);
```

Comment: You are doing Password Based Encryption, the reason why you require password.

Comment: @user3020494 ok but this password is not asked for again. Is it used as part of the algoruithm for generating the encrypted password ?

Comment: In the same session you are setting the password, encrypting and decrypting the text. Try decrypting the encrypted text without setting the password in another session.. it wont work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It does work and it does require password for encryption and decryption. To simplify the example I have initiated two sessions of StandardPBEStringEncryptor as encryptor and decryptor

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StandardPBEStringEncryptor encryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPassword("mySecretPassword");        
    String encryptedText = encryptor.encrypt("Hello World");
    System.out.println("Encrypted text is: " + encryptedText);

    StandardPBEStringEncryptor decryptor = new StandardPBEStringEncryptor();
    decryptor.setPassword("mySecretPassword");  
    String decryptedText = decryptor.decrypt(encryptedText);
    System.out.println("Decrypted text is: " + decryptedText);
    }
```

output:

```
Encrypted text is: +pBbr+KOb7D6Ap/5vYJIUoHbhOruls+L
Decrypted text is: Hello World
```

Comment: it seems liks a security convern encoding the password within code, should this be read from a secure location ?

Comment: There has to be trust somewhere - if one uses more complex public/private key pairs to encrypt and decrypt information, then private key needs to be stored in safe place. In java world - a keystore, even keystore is password protected... hence where to save the password - in kernel or in program or in memory - all have their pros and cons.