# What are the default values used for StandardPBEStringEncryptor class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, encryption, jasypt

I gone through the following post. what are the default values used in StandardPBEStringEncryptor class i.e which algorithm,Salt generator,no of hashing,etc?
Any Link providing all those values.

[[1]: [Why set a password using jasypt when encrypting text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176040/why-set-a-password-using-jasypt-when-encrypting-text][1])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well sometimes source codes are the best documentation for this kind of problems. `Jasypt` 's source codes are easy to read and its javadoc is pretty good. By reading its source code from `StandardPBEStringEncryptor#encrypt` , I find the default values for the following settings :

- `SaltGenerator` uses [**SHA1PRNG**](https://github.com/tfredrich/jasypt/blob/e391a261fd88e6ca660db5a27060db0b376241c1/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/salt/RandomSaltGenerator.java#L52) algorithm to generate secure random number.
- Use [**PBEWithMD5AndDES**](https://github.com/tfredrich/jasypt/blob/e391a261fd88e6ca660db5a27060db0b376241c1/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java#L133) for encryption algorithm
- Number of hashing iterations applied for obtaining the encryption key [**1000**](https://github.com/tfredrich/jasypt/blob/e391a261fd88e6ca660db5a27060db0b376241c1/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java#L139)
- The salt size is [**8** bytes](https://github.com/tfredrich/jasypt/blob/e391a261fd88e6ca660db5a27060db0b376241c1/jasypt/src/main/java/org/jasypt/encryption/pbe/StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java#L145)

Comment: Thanks.I got my answer ,please upvote the question .